# Text size on my monitor

Tags: display

The text on my monitor is extremely small, almost unreadable.I downloaded the NOOBS software, I am using an HDMI lead and a television monitor with HDMI input. Also trying to run the Scratch program which says to move a block of code from the left panel and locking the bars should move the image according to to code, eg "move 10 steps" nothing happens, just a small movement.
Regards Steve

Comment: Just ask about the text size problem on this question and move the bit about Scratch programming to another question.

Answer (score 2):

about the text size...

1. run

   ls -l /usr/share/consolefonts | less
2. pick a font you like
3. then run

   setfont [font name sans extension]

I'm using (I'm pulling this from memory)

```
setfont Uni2-Terminus48x24
```

**the less command will allow you to scroll the screen using the up and down arrows keys. run with and without the | less and you'll see the difference